# JHipster 7.1.0 ReactJS building jar

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, jhipster

I try to build a simple app with JHipster.
I create the app with

> $jhipster

After I add some entities with

> $jhipster jdl jhipster-jdl.jdl

Everything is working fine, I can launch the app with ./mvnw and acces it. It's all good.
But when i try to build a jar with

> $./mvnw -Pprod verify clean

I tried to add '/hipster/' in webpack.prod.js or webpack.common.js (https://www.jhipster.tech/production/) but it change nothing.

I have the error :

> > [INFO] > test@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT webapp:build:prod [INFO] > npm run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --progress=profile [INFO]
> > [INFO]  [INFO] > test@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT webpack [INFO] > node
> > --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js "--config" "webpack/webpack.prod.js" "--progress=profile"
>
> > [INFO] [webpack-cli] Failed to load '/home/charles/Code/Campus/test/webpack/webpack.prod.js' config
>
> > [INFO] [webpack-cli] Error: Cannot find module 'workbox-build/build/options/schema/webpack-generate-sw'
>
> > [INFO] Require stack: [INFO] - /home/charles/Code/Campus/test/node_modules/workbox-webpack-plugin/build/generate-sw.js
>
> > [INFO] - /home/charles/Code/Campus/test/node_modules/workbox-webpack-plugin/build/index.js
>
> > [INFO] - /home/charles/Code/Campus/test/webpack/webpack.prod.js
>
> > [INFO] - /home/charles/Code/Campus/test/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js
>
> > [INFO] - /home/charles/Code/Campus/test/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/bootstrap.js
>
> > [INFO] - /home/charles/Code/Campus/test/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js
>
> > [INFO] - /home/charles/Code/Campus/test/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
>
> > [INFO]     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
>
> > [INFO]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
>
> > [INFO]     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
>
> > [INFO]     at require (/home/charles/Code/Campus/test/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
>
> > [INFO]     at Object. (/home/charles/Code/Campus/test/node_modules/workbox-webpack-plugin/build/generate-sw.js:20:33)
>
> > [INFO]     at Module._compile (/home/charles/Code/Campus/test/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
>
> > [INFO]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
>
> > [INFO]     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
>
> > [INFO]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
>
> > [INFO]     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19) {
>
> > [INFO]   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
>
> > [INFO]   requireStack: [
>
> > [INFO]     '/home/charles/Code/Campus/test/node_modules/workbox-webpack-plugin/build/generate-sw.js',
>
> > [INFO]     '/home/charles/Code/Campus/test/node_modules/workbox-webpack-plugin/build/index.js',
>
> > [INFO]     '/home/charles/Code/Campus/test/webpack/webpack.prod.js',
>
> > [INFO]     '/home/charles/Code/Campus/test/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js',
>
> > [INFO]     '/home/charles/Code/Campus/test/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/bootstrap.js',
>
> > [INFO]     '/home/charles/Code/Campus/test/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js',
>
> > [INFO]     '/home/charles/Code/Campus/test/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js'

And the error from Maven :

> [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time:  19.942 s [INFO] Finished at:
> 2021-08-24T08:57:01+02:00 [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.12.0:npm (webapp build
> prod) on project jhipster: Failed to run task: 'npm run webapp:prod'
> failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with
> an error: 2 (Exit value: 2) -> [Help 1] [ERROR]  [ERROR] To see the
> full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
> [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible
> solutions, please read the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1]
> http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

Comment: So far, you did not show errors from maven output, only infos that are wrongly displayed as error by maven frontend plugin. Please edit your question with real error

Comment: Done. But I found the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it can help I found the solution in the package.json I changed :

> "workbox-webpack-plugin": "6.1.5"

to

> "workbox-webpack-plugin": "6.2.4"

Comment: Glad you found a solution, this version is already used on JHipster's main branch, so it will be included in next JHipster release.